# caching dom element using namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to chache DOM using namespace but when I call I get "undefined" instead of jQuery object

```
  <form id="create_profile">  

      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <input type="text" name="password" />
      <input type="text" name="passwordconfirm" />

      <span onclick="profile.create()">valider</span>

 </form>
```

Js:

```
 var profile = {

  create: function(){

   alert(profileFields.test); // show done!
   alert(profileFields.create_form.attr('id')); // show undefined instead of create_profil

  }


}

var profileFields = {

        test: "done!",  
        create_form: $("#create_profile"),
        $email: $("input[name='name']", this.create_form),
        $password: $("input[name='pass']", this.create_form),
        $passwordconfirm: $("input[name='passconfirm']", this.create_form),
        $name: $("input[name='email']", this.create_form),
        $tel: $("input[name='tel']",this.create_form)  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tells us that your JavaScript code is running *before* that element exists, so `$("#create_profile")` returns an empty jQuery object. Calling `attr` on an empty jQuery object returns `undefined`. If your `script` tag is higher up in the HTML than the elements it refers to, the elements won't exist as of when the script runs.

Either

1. Put the `script` tag at the very end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or
2. Use jQuery's `ready` to hold up execution of your code until "DOM ready."

#1 is preferred unless you don't control where the `script` tag goes. More:

- [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure engineers on when DOM elements are ready for scripting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E/RjllWWJTXAcJ)

Comment: Putting script snippets everywhere in the code, sacrificing maintainability is a premature optimization if you are not experiencing any performance issues. I wouln't advocate that it should be the default practice. How usable can your site be without being fully loaded anyway? It's all case by case and depends on the nature of the application and the modules themselves.

Comment: @plalx: Please read #1 again: *"Put the `script` tag at the very end of the HTML, jut before the closing `</body>` tag"* Not "everywhere in the code." In **one**, clearly-defined, easily-located place.

Comment: Sorry, that was in response to the google's forum discussion.

Comment: @plalx: Ah, yes, that's where I have the temerity to part company with the Google folks. :-) The point of that link is just that the elements are ready much earlier than people seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

You probably simply did not wait until the DOM was ready.

Wrap your code in:

```
$(function () {
    //your code
});
```